# USB Gamepad device descriptor with feedback

Tags: usb, microcontroller, pic

I'm working on a USB HID gamepad device (PIC18F45K50). I need to have data (14 buttons) sent from the gamepad to the pc. In addition I need to have data sent from the PC to the gamepad, 1 for on-off functionality and another for dimming of a backlight (0-255 would be fine).

I currently have the gamepad device descriptor working fine, however I am having a very difficult time determining how to implement the PC to gamepad side of the descriptor. I have not been able to find much info regarding this.

Anyone have experience and could shed some light on this?

My current device descriptor is below.

Thanks!

```
    0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x04,                    // USAGE (Gamepad)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x09, 0x04,                    //   USAGE (Gamepad)
    0xa1, 0x00,                    //   COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x05, 0x09,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x0E,                    //     USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 14)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x95, 0x0E,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (14)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x95, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x02,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (2)
    0x81, 0x01,                    //     INPUT (Cnst,Ary,Abs)
    0xc0,                          //     END_COLLECTION
    0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
```